# Java8 Nashorn - ReferenceError: "eu" is not defined

Tags: java, javascript, java-8, nashorn

I'm trying to call a static method on a class from JavaScript executed by Nashorn:

```
var hooks = new JavaImporter(eu.wansdyke.carbon.hooks);
with (hooks) {
  Archiver.archive(bucket, key, existingValue, 1);
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "eu" is not defined in  at line number 2
```

The class that invokes Nashorn is in a eu.wansdyke... package so I'm a bit surprised at this. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: We'll need to see how `eu` is defined, I guess? but I'm guessing it's inside a different colsure so not referenceable from the outside world. Also, **please note that _Java_ and _JavaScript_ only share similar names and are different languages**.

Comment: I'm aware that they're different. This is JavaScript invoked from Java. Hence I haven't explicitly defined eu as it's a Java package, although the code is JavaScript.

Comment: The cause for your problem is that Nashorn loads the `java.*`, `javax.*` and `com.*` packet hierarchies into global scope, but not `eu.*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you access it through the Packages object, I think it will work.

For instance:

```
Packages.eu.wansdyke.carbon.hooks
```

For referenced pull it from the : [Nashorn Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html)

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tried this and it works great :)  Much cleaner than the Java.type suggestion IMHO

Answer (score 1):

The cause for your problem is that Nashorn loads the `java.*`, `javax.*`, `javafx.*`, `com.*`, `edu.*` and `org.*` packet hierarchies into global scope, but not `eu.*`. That means you can not reference that package directly.

But you should be able to import individual classes from the `eu.*` hierarchy with `Java.type(String)`.

```
 var Archiver = Java.type("eu.wansdyke.carbon.hooks.Archiver");
 Archiver.archive(bucket, key, existingValue, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

More of a workaround than a satisfactory answer, but I've been able to set an instance of the Archiver class as a global variable on the JS runtime using void javax.script.ScriptEngine.put(String key, Object value). A static method didn't seem to then be available so I've used an instance one and called a static method from it.